# How to mock groups and users for a jira plugin

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, jira

I'm currently in the middle of making an Atlassian Plugin for Jira. To test some of my conditions for my plugin, I'd like to mock a user and a group and check whether that user is in that group or not. However, before the test is run, I want to assign that mocked user to the mocked group. I tried using this to mock it:

```
Group mockedGroup = Mockito.mock(Group.class);
```

I also tried making a new group with a mocked GroupManager, but no success either.

Any advice is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Search through JIRA sources (you can download them in your Atlassaian account under which you bough JIRA). There you will find plenty samples. I think I see the code you need in FilteredCrowdServiceImplTest.java, testAddUserToGroupNormal.